# Small sample in opengl es 3, wrong gamma correction

Tags: opengl-es, jogl, srgb

I have a small sample, [es-300-fbo-srgb](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/es_300/Es_300_fbo_srgb.java), supposed to showing how to manage gamma correction in opengl es3.

Essentially I have:

- a `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` texture `TEXTURE_DIFFUSE`
- a framebuffer with another `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` texture on `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and a `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` texture on `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`
- the back buffer of my default fbo is `GL_LINEAR`
- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` initially disabled.

I get [image: this]

instead of [image: this]

Now, if I recap the `display` metho, this is what I do:

- I render the `TEXTURE_DIFFUSE` texture on the sRGB fbo and since the source texture is in sRGB space, my fragment shader will read automatically a linear value and write it to the fbo. Fbo should contain now linear values, although it is sRGB, because `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is disabled, so no linear->sRGB conversion is executed.
- I blit the content of the fbo to the default fbo back buffer (through a program). But since the texture of this fbo has the sRGB component, on the read values a wrong gamma operation will be performed  because they are assumed in sRGB space when they are not.
- a second gamma operation is performed by my monitor when it renders the content of the default fbo

So my image is, if I am right, twice as wrong..

Now, if I `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);` I get instead [image: this]

The image looks like it have been too many times sRGB corrected..

If I, instead, leave the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` disabled and change the format of the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` texture of my fbo, I get finally the right image..

Why do I not get the correct image with `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);`?

Comment: would you mind give me a simple example for gamma correction with openGL? I can't find any thing on internet :((

Comment: Sure, [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples) you go

Answer (score 0):

I think you are basically right: you get the net effect of two decoding conversions where one (the one in your monitor) would be enough. I suppose that either your driver or your code breaks something so OpenGL doesn't 'connect the dots' properly; perhaps this answer helps you:

[When to call glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386199/when-to-call-glenablegl-framebuffer-srgb)

Comment: The default fbo is `GL_LINEAR` by default. In the meanwhile, I solved by enabling `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` at the [first passage](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/es_300/Es_300_fbo_srgb.java#L349) and disabling it at the [second one](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/es_300/Es_300_fbo_srgb.java#L376) but I can't explain why it works..

Comment: Good it works now! I meant to say that GL_LINEAR is not opposite to GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB or any other lightness encoding constant as GL_LINEA,R TTBOMK, determines interpolation. It sounds like a complement but it isn't, and should not be relevant here.

Comment: I remember they are, look [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter) "If _pname​_ is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING`, _param​_ will contain the encoding of components of the specified attachment, one of `GL_LINEAR` or `GL_SRGB` for linear or sRGB-encoded components, respectively.

Comment: I see it's been reused for that. Good to know, thanks!